# Printing WinForm with controls using PrintDocument component c#

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, printdocument

I'm really not interested in having someone else do my job for me, I would really just appreciate a point in the right direction.

I have a couple of Forms that need to be printed. All of them consisting of multiple datagridviews and other controls. Jobcards, manufacturing sheets, stock cutting lists, quotes, etc etc..

I have tried so many possible solutions on the internet. The PrintForm component is practically useless because of poor resolution. I've tried Crystal Report, with some success, I use it to generate and print my quotes and invoices.

'Capturing' the form (Bitmap) ...(witch I guess in my case is a slightly better alternative to printForm) Doesnt cut it ether.

[MSDN Printing the Form (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287529%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

I'm rather demotivated, since this is the very last part of my application before testing.
I really want to understand and learn everything I can about the PrintDocument Component so I can FINALLY solve this problem and gain some VS-printing experience.

I'm about to get in depth with iText-Sharp now as my last resort. so please tell me if it will prove to be fruitless(in my case atleast;) That would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you kind Sir or Lady for your time and possibly your knowledge

Kindest regards

Herman Vercuiel
[image: New Order Form]
Quote Form that also generates similarly in Crystal Reports
[image]

The forms that I need to print... The amount of Forms vary depending on the type and amount of products ordered.

[image]

EDIT:

I'm settling for this at the moment..

How can I make sure this is fitted into one page?
currently a part of the right side of the form is missing.

```
private void CaptureScreen()
        {
            Graphics mygraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            Size s = this.Size;
            memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, mygraphics);
            Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
            IntPtr dc1 = mygraphics.GetHdc();
            IntPtr dc2 = memoryGraphics.GetHdc();
            BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, dc1, 0, 0, 13369376);
            mygraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc1);
            memoryGraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc2);
        }
```

Comment: Those worried about saving the trees (like myself) all these forms will eventually appear on touchscreens at each respective manufacturing machine:) [this also is my motivation against using Crystal report for these forms] and most orders are done online, so the customer receive their quotes and invoices in pdf form:) ... The company just want to test the software from the 1st of June.

Comment: checking out http://www.winformreports.co.uk/ at the moment

Comment: Printing controls is never going to make anybody happy, printers have a resolution that's x6 better than a monitor.  So every pixel turns into a 6x6 blob on paper.  You just forgot about the other 90% of your project, very unclear what you hope us to do about that.

Comment: @HansPassant So sorry If I was unclear. I am aware that printing controls is definitely not good practice, especially in a relatively professional environment. (**Hence using Crystal Reports for customer documentation.**) This is only a some what of a temporary solution, as I said,  these forms are intended to be displayed on touchscreens. I'm aware of the difference in resolution between screen and printer:) Also not sure what you meant by "You just forgot about the other 90% of your project" Thank you for commenting

Answer (score 0):

The controls on a form are optimized to be rendered on a low-res raster device (the screen).
The print are optimized to be rendered on a hi-res raster device  (the printer).

So, if you render a form to a printer, you may get a very tiny print, or a big print with low res (like the screen).

I'm not an expert of printing... but the only way I can think of printing a form on paper without having the low-res big ugly pixel is to re-render all the form objects: enumerate all the controls on the form, and draw by yourself the controls the way you want, so you can decide exactly how to render them in hi-res. So youcan decide the looks of the border of a button, a combo box, whatever...

Implementing something like this looks like a very big job...

**Update**
Another, simpler, option may be to use a bitmap to raster converter.
You can grab the screen as a bitmap, pass the bitmap in a raster-to-vector converter, obtain a vecotrialized version of your bitmap, and then you can directly print this  vector-based image.

But automated raster-to-vector conversion may works... or may not work.
Your mileage may vary.

Maybe you can try "by-hand" to grab the screen and do a bitmap-to-vector conversion using some free tools, like [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) (start Inkskape, import the bitmap, then go in menu Path\Trace Bitmap, and try out the various options (color, BW, smoothing...)).
Then if you have good results, maybe [you can find a raster-to bitmap tool](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=bitmap%20to%20vector%20library&oq=bitmap%20to%20vector%20library) to integrate in you application.

Comment: Hi there Max, Firstly thank you for your answer.

Comment: That does sound like a pretty big job. I rate It would be best to suck it up and have slightly blurry manufacturing sheets during the application trials